# C++ Convert a parameter pack of types to parameter pack of indices

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, c++14

Is there any way to convert a parameter pack of types to a parameter pack of integers from `0` to `sizeof...(Types)`? More specifically, I'm trying to do something this this:

```
template <size_t... I>
  void bar();

template <typename... Types>
  void foo() {
    bar<WHAT_GOES_HERE<Types>...>();
  }
```

For example, `foo<int,float,double>()` should call `bar<0, 1, 2>()`;

In my use case the parameter pack `Types` may contain the same type multiple times, so I cannot search the pack to compute the index for a given type.

Comment: what is the real problem ? I'm sure we can provide better suggestion.

Comment: what's the benefit of `bar<0, 1, 2>()` over `bar<3>()`?

Comment: If I have `template <typename... Args> void g(Args&&...);` and `template <size_t  I> auto h();`. I'd like to be able to do `g(h<I>()...);` from the parameter pack given to `foo()`. TartanLlama's solution works. I'm using these template hacks to implement the copy constructor of a "struct of array" container type which itself uses variadic templates to define the types.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++14 you can use `std::index_sequence_for` from the `<utility>` header along with tagged dispatch. This is known as the *indices trick*:

```
template <std::size_t... I>
void bar(std::index_sequence<I...>);

template <typename... Types>
void foo() {
    bar(std::index_sequence_for<Types...>{});
}
```

If you are limited to C++11, you can find many implementations of the above online, such as [this one](https://gist.github.com/doicanhden/7249956).

Comment: @RyanHaining There must be at least half a dozen implementations of `integer_sequence` and friends on SO alone.

Comment: @T.C. I'm sure, but in c++11 it's not going to be in `<utility>` so the answer is misleading.  linking to an implementation would be useful here

Comment: C++14 is ok for me. I've changed the tags on the question. Anyway as others have said integer sequences can be reimplemented if not available.