# Constructing a type using parameter pack of types and an input array of corresponding values

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, stdtuple

Before posting this question, I have already tried to fit the approaches mentioned over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer?lq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054068/c-convert-a-parameter-pack-of-types-to-parameter-pack-of-indices) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951058/transform-a-variadic-pack-of-types-into-values). However, nothing could solve my requirement as I have an intermediate function that needs some adjustments.

Essentially,what I have is as follows. I have to construct the type `T` based on the arguments whose types are stored in parameter pack `Args` and corresponding values in the array `ARGValue *ptr`

However, to map the values of type from `ARGValue* ptr` to a type in `Args...`
I need to do an intermediate operation which is as below.

```
    // Specialization for 1 argument

        template<typename T,typename... Args>
        struct instance_helper<T,1,Args...>
        {   
            static T invokeConstructor(const ARGValue *ptr)
            {   
                // Intermediate operation
                typedef typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Args...> >::type TT;
                const auto val0 = *(someUglyCast<TT*>(ptr[0])) ;

                // Return the desired type 
                return T(val0);
            }
        };

     //Specialization for no argument

        template<typename T,typename... Args>
        struct instance_helper<T,0,Args...>
        {   
            static T invokeConstructor(const ARGValue*)
            {   
                return T(); 
            }   
        };  

     // General Case
        template<typename T,size_t packSize,typename... Args>
        struct instance_helper
        {   
            static T invokeConstructor(const ARGValue *ptr)
            {             
                // Do some recursive magic here for intermediate operation
                return T(//Do some recursive magic) ;
            }   
        };
```

How do I solve this? How can I safely get the values for all the types in `Args...` from `ARGValue*` and then construct the type `T`?

I do not want to create specializations for multiple arguments as it might clutter the code.

Comment: Is there a possibility to supply argument values from a tuple instead ?

Comment: @Quentin Nope.Only separate/individual arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want:

```
template<typename T,size_t packSize,typename... Args>
struct instance_helper
{
    static T invokeConstructor(const ARGValue *ptr)
    {
         return invokeConstructor(std::make_index_sequence<packSize>{}, ptr);
    }   

private:
    template <std::size_t ... Is>
    static T invokeConstructor(std::index_sequence<Is...>, const ARGValue *ptr)
    {
        using Tuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
            // Do some recursive magic here for intermediate operation
        return T((*(someUglyCast<const std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>*>(ptr[Is])))...) ;
    }
};
```

Comment: `std::make_index_sequence` is not supported by our compilers here. :(  :(

Comment: @Recker there are plenty of implementations online. Like [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence).